# Erro getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: javascript, java, html, aplicação-web, jsp

Tenho em minha aplicação o seguinte erro:

getOutputStream() has already been called for this response.

Ok, o trecho de código que está causando este erro é o seguinte:

```
boolean hasLogoLogin = new BrandResourceDao().selectByTag(BrandResourceCnt.TAG_BRANDLOGOLOGIN) != null;
boolean hasLogoDefault = new BrandResourceDao().selectByTag(BrandResourceCnt.TAG_BRANDLOGODEFAULT) != null;
boolean hasLogoHight = new BrandResourceDao()
            .selectByTag(BrandResourceCnt.TAG_BRANDLOGOHIGHLIGHTEDE) != null;
boolean hasBackground = new BrandResourceDao().selectByTag(BrandResourceCnt.TAG_BRANDBACKGROUND) != null;
```

Que não é nada mais do que um select para verificar se as imagens salvas em um determinado momento na aplicação realmente estão lá. O código logo abaixo é repetido para cada retorno dos selects acima(Cada um para o seu valor).

```
<img id="imgLogoLogin"
    <%=hasLogoLogin
       ? "src='loadImage.jsp?" + Params.TAG + "=" + BrandResourceCnt.TAG_BRANDLOGOLOGIN + "'" : ""%>
style="max-width: 325px; max-height: 200px; width: auto; height: auto;" />
```

E aqui o loadImage.jsp que busca no banco a imagem, converte e exibe na aplicação.

```
try {
        String tag = request.getParameter(Params.TAG);
        BrandResourceDao dao = new BrandResourceDao();
        BrandResource brand = dao.selectByTag(tag);

if (brand != null) {
   byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(brand.getValue());
   response.setContentType("image/gif");
   OutputStream oImage = response.getOutputStream();  <-- É culpa desse cara aí
   oImage.write(bytes);
   oImage.flush();
   oImage.close();
}
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Por favor sem xingamentos pelo style da tag (img) vou colocá-la no css no futuro.

Bom minha duvida é: Como resolver isso? Preciso mudar a estrutura é óbvio. Porem sou iniciante e não sei como faze-lo. Alguém tem alguma ideia pra agilizar a minha vida com isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz parte da API do Java que você somente pode recuperar uma única vez um objeto de saída a partir do *response*, seja através do método `getOutputStream` ou do método `getWriter`.

Se o código em questão está dentro de um JSP, você já tem um [objeto implícito `out`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm) que pode usar para escrever os dados. Chamar o método `response.getOutputStream` não somente é desnecessário como um erro.

A diferença aqui é que o `out` é do tipo `PrintWriter`, então você vai ter que adaptar o código um pouco.

Isso significa que não é possível escrever uma saída de bytes a partir de um JSP. Eu já vi implementações que convertiam os bytes para uma String e então escreviam a String usando `out.write(str)`, porém há casos onde pode haver perda da informação.

A saída ideal para o seu caso é não usar um JSP, mas escrever um Servlet onde você possa usar o `getOutputStream` devidamente.

Exemplo ([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623747/1683070)):

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

       ServletContext cntx= getServletContext();
      // Get the absolute path of the image
      String filename = cntx.getRealPath("Images/button.png");
      // retrieve mimeType dynamically
      String mime = cntx.getMimeType(filename);
      if (mime == null) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return;
      }

      resp.setContentType(mime);
      File file = new File(filename);
      resp.setContentLength((int)file.length());

      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
      OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

      // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
       byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
       int count = 0;
       while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
         out.write(buf, 0, count);
      }
    out.close();
    in.close();

}
```

Comment: Terias algum exemplo pra indicar? Todos os que encontrei estão chamando o getOutputStream().

Comment: @CesarRobertoMartins Atualizei a resposta com mais informações

Comment: Hum. . . Sou iniciante como já disse, já vi em vários exemplos por ai de código escrito da mesma maneira. Acho que fica bom e organizado. Porem não posso usar o mesmo. Estou no trabalho, e fui instruído a não utilizar este modelo de projeto. Não há uma solução mais "simples" no caso do modelo que já tenho aqui?

Comment: @CesarRobertoMartins Queria poder ir na sua empresa falar com quem quer que seja que disse isso. A resposta oficial é: com JSP não dá. Ninguém em sã consciência faz isso. Servlets ou Controllers (se usando algum framework) são o jeito certo de fazer isso. O resto é gambiarra. Com e eu disso na resposta, dá pra *tentar* converter os bytes para uma String e imprimir isso na saída, mas não há garantia alguma de que a imagem não será corrompida.

Comment: Bom de qualquer forma irei comunicar isso ao líder do projeto e direi isso a ele. Vejamos o que ele tem em mente. Enquanto isso, vou resolvendo o que posso. Muito obrigado pela resposta, foi de grande ajuda.